# Wordpress Menus - How to add inline styles to UL menus

Tags: menus, jquery

I've just converted my HTML version of a theme over to Wordpress, and I'm currently converting the dropdown menus over.

**What WordPress processes:**

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li id="menu-item-190" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-190"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-185" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-185"><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-183" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-183"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-179" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-179"><a href="#">Drop-downs</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-189" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-189"><a href="#">Page one</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-188" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-188"><a href="#">Page two</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-187" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-187"><a href="#">Page three</a></li>
            </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-177" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-177"><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
</ul>
```

On page load, this is what my menu is showing:

```
<ul class="sub-menu">
```

I'd like it to show:

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

**What WordPress is currently doing:**
On load the dropdown menu is currently showing. Screenshot: http://d.pr/i/KMxL - I only want it to show when hovered over, but since converting it from my raw HTML/CSS it's just showing up on page load, but when I do hover over and/or hover off it works fine.

**My jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.dropdown li").hover(function() {
    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass("hover");
        $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
});
```

I'm not quite sure how to get WordPress to add 'style="visibility: hidden;"' to this. Does anyone have any idea?

**Note:** If I've missed anything I'll add it, sorry. Furthermore, I'm using the WordPress menus. Using: **add_theme_support('menus');**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add a CSS rule like so: `ul.sub-menu { visibility: hidden; }`.

Comment: Already had this implemented, but it seems when I did it (last night at 4am) I miss spelt the nav so it didn't work... I just double checked and it works now, haha. Sorry, can't believe I missed that. Thank you.